# How do you mock an OpenCascade?

Tags: ruby, rspec

OpenCascade is a recursive OpenStruct from Hashery:

http://rubyworks.github.com/hashery/

It allows you to refer to nested values in a hash via a sequence of keys:

```
h = {:a=>1,:b=>{:x=>1,:y=>2}}
c = OpenCascade.new(h)
c.b.y
=> 2
```

We're using it to read in a YAML config.  Now we'd like to mock the values in tests, however

```
mock(c.b).y { 5 }
```

doesn't work.  How do we mock it?

Comment: OpenCascade is a brilliant class. It's what I've been looking for to store application settings. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When the question was asked the implementation of `OpenCascade`'s [`method_missing`](https://github.com/rubyworks/hashery/blob/5fab2c5e30c0701738e451d0cd85d59f72453f01/lib/hashery/opencascade.rb) created a new object each time a `Hash` was queried:

```
def method_missing(sym, *args, &blk)
  # ...snip..
  if key?(name)
    self[name] = transform_entry(self[name])
  # ...snip...
  end
end

private

#
def transform_entry(entry)
  case entry
  when Hash
    OpenCascade.new(entry) #self.class.new(val)
  when Array
    entry.map{ |e| transform_entry(e) }
  else
    entry
  end
end
```

This means that in that version the following:

```
c.b equal? c.b
# => false
```

That's why mocking `c.b` didn't work...

It has since been fixed.